# Xamarin Forms Android Pie Not Getting Current Location in App Background Sleep Mode

Tags: android, xamarin, location

I want to get current location, when app went into sleep mode or Background.Currently i am using > `Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current DLL` in App `OnSleep()` , But Its Working Till Android `8.1` but `Android Pie` Not updating **current Location** Values.. How to Achieve in Android Pie?

Sample Code :

```
 protected override async void OnSleep()
 {
 var minute = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
 Device.StartTimer(minute, () =>
 { 
 await Task.Run(async () =>
 {
 TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
 var locator = Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current;
 locator.DesiredAccuracy = 5;
 var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout: t); 
 //API Method
 });
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just spin up a thread and expect it to keep running after the OS places the app into the background or battery saving mode.

You will have to setup an Android `Service` (and foreground it) *at a minimum* to handle your location updates.

#### Background Execution Limits

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

#### Foreground Services

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

#### Schedule tasks with WorkManager

- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try with help of service. One more doubt its possible to stop the **Running Service** at time of App Killing?

Comment: @AnbuMani Certainly, killing the app's process will kill everything. You can look at using WorkManager to restart your Service on a periodic basis, or by sending a remote notification to the device, etc... but there is never a guarantee that it will run constantly, that is just not how Android apps are designed to execute.