# Android service is stopped

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-service, background-process

I write an Android application with Xamarin. This app performs some long-running task, show notifications for user and should do it in background. As I know I should use Service for this purpose. I created my service, here is its code:

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);     

    var thread = new Thread(new Runnable(() => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++)
        {
            ShowNotification("channel", "Search", $"second: {i}, threadId: {id} startId: {startId}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }                           
        StopSelf(startId);
    }));
    thread.Start();

    return StartCommandResult.StartSticky;
}
```

And code of `ShowNotification` method:

```
protected void ShowNotification(string channel, string title, string message)
{
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, GetType());
    resultIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    var resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    var mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
        .SetContentText(message)
        .SetAutoCancel(false)
        .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    if (!(GetSystemService(NotificationService) is NotificationManager mNotificationManager))
        return;

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        var importance = NotificationImportance.High;
        var notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel, channel, importance);
        notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.LightColor = Color.Red;
        notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });
        mBuilder.SetChannelId(channel);
        mNotificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    mNotificationManager.Notify(0, mBuilder.Build());
}
```

This code works but after 2-5 minutes service is stopped and new notifications are not shown. Is it posible to forbid stopping my service (or restart it after stopping)? I heard I should return flag START_STICKY  from method OnStartCommand and I use it. But it doesn't work and operating system stops my service anyway. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Newer versions of Android has implemented background execution limits to prevent battery drain, performance issues, etc.. from having every installed app running their own task in the background. The *first* step would be "foregrounding" your Service to tell the OS and show the user that your app is running in the background: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services Also review the links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360473/4984832 regarding background limitations and things like the new WorkManager

Comment: @SushiHangover it works in background but is called 'foreground'? Sounds weird

Comment: It is "Foreground" due to the fact that it requires a permanent notification placed into the notification bar while this app is still running so the user is aware of it

Answer (score 0):

As SushiHangover already said you have to call `startForeground()` at OnStartCommand()
and when you start the server call `startForegroundService()`